# Cancel a POST request

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an app that makes a request to a server to generate an audio file and the problem that I have is that if I send two distinct and consecutive requests, I can not cancel the first. I tried with .unload or .unloadAndStop but always gives me error.

Any suggestions?

```
        elfich="sonido" + elfichnum;
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        variables.text=caja_texto;
        variables.fileName=elfich;
        request.url = "http://192.168.0.19:800/cgi-bin/tts.cgi";
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = variables;
        loader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cargacompletanew);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrornew);
        loader.load(request);
    }

    function cargacompletanew(event:Event):void
    {
        xlocalSound = new Sound(); 
        var xreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://192.168.0.19:800/output/" + elfich + ".mp3"); 
        xlocalSound.load(xreq);
        xlocalSound.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, iniciarSonido);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cargacompletanew);
loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrornew);
loader.close();
```

I think there was a problem with `close()` if you were trying to close it if nothing was loaded, so I'd try to put that inn try/catch block.

```
try 
{
  loader.close();
}
catch(e:Error) 
{
  loader("Oh noes!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I could do the loader.close. The loader.unloadAndStop instruction, gives me the following error:
Calling a method unloadAndStop possibly not defined by reference with static type flash.net:URLLoader.

Thank you.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, `unloadAndStop` was in `Loader` calss, not `URLLoader`. So in this case just call `.close()`